# Rails and Postgres: Getting the latest entry for each customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model (which has been simplified here) that looks like this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name
    has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :description, :cost, :date
end
```

I'm using Postgres – what's the best way to run a query that will return me a single result that contains the latest order for each customer?

If I do something like this:

```
Order.order('date DESC').group('customer')
```

Then I get a Postgres error:

```
PGError: ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

What's the cleanest way to do this? I'm a Rails newbie, so let me know if I've left out any vital information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as question says **Getting the latest entry for each customer**

```
Customer.all.map{|C| [c.name, c.orders.last]}
```

will return an array with customer name and latest order. In view it will look like this:

```
<% @customers.each do |c| %>
 <%= c.name %> - <%= c.orders.last.cost %>
<% end %>
```

result:

```
  John Travolta - $5454
  Johnny Depp   - $6849
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Order.order('date DESC').group('customer_id')
```

I guess your Order model does not have customer field by convention it should be customer_id

Answer (score 0):

For a more SQL oriented method, which ought to be better performing:

```
Order.where("id in (select max(id) from orders group by customer_id)")
```

It relies on the most recent order having the highest id.